# css float gets double margin on top (not from body)

Tags: html, css, double, margin

I'm new to css and I'm having a margin problem with a float element that gets a 20px margin on top, even though its margin is 10px.
I've been looking at several topics, where body default margins seem to be the problem, but that's not it. Anyone knows why this double margin is showing up?

I think it's due to my div container on the side, because if I set its top margin to 0, then the floated element has a normal 10px top margin (not 20px). I just don't understand how the div can be affecting the floated element.

ps: I'm using firefox

[image: double margin]

html:

```
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Products</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Plan B</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
    <h2> Products</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Product category</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href="">Product category</a></li><!--
      --><li><a href="">Product category</a></li><!--
       --><li><a href="">Product category</a></li><!--
       --><li><a href="">Productcategory</a></li><!--
--></ul>
    <p>hello there!
       etc..</p>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border; 0;
}

/* -------------- SIDEBAR ---------------- */

nav ul {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;               /* HERE */
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
    color:black;
    padding: 0;
    bordeR; 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}



/* --------------CONTENT AREA---------------- */
div.content {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 180px;   /* if top margin set to 0, it works */
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.content h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

div.content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}

div.content ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


div.content ul li a {
    background-color: pink;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0;
}

div.content p {
    font-size: 110%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This is how I would do it](http://jsbin.com/jidafavovu/1/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a margin on all you li's ...do this:

```
nav ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

when you use `:first-child` you are telling that your first li margin-top is 0

Comment: I agree with this.  You're getting 10px all the way around, including the top, which effectively makes it 20px in between anyway.

Comment: That worked, thank you! :) But I still don't quite get it..if instead of adding 10px to all <li> tags, I add 10px just to the <ul> tag, I still get 20px on top, instead of 10 :S

Comment: please click on the correct answer icon :) ... i tryed on friddle and it was only a 10px gap ...let me check again

Comment: i only can see 10px on the top ..check this : https://jsfiddle.net/aladdinl/07b7pfrr/  do you use firebug ? its 10

Comment: I just installed it, thanks for the tip! :) Nevermind about what I just said, it just shows a 10px margin if I add it to <ul> instead of to <li>. I just find it weird that if I remove my side div 10px top margin,my sidebar's extra margin disappears, but the opposite doesn't happen

Comment: firebug is your new best friend...you can use it to change your css and see it live (it dosent saves anything but u can debug as u go)